# Set background color Java JButton

Tags: java, macos, jbutton, setbackground

I tried to modify the background color of my JButton (and the size) but it doesn't work (the foreground is by the way ok)

```
public class boutondesign extends JButton implements MouseListener {
private String name; 


public boutondesign(String nom){
        super(nom);
        this.name = nom; 
        this.setSize(100, 100); 
        this.addMouseListener(this); 
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.setForeground(Color.white);
```

thanks in advance for yours answers

following the first advice :

```
public boutondesign(String nom){
    super(nom);
    this.name = nom;  
    this.addMouseListener(this); 
    this.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    this.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    this.setOpaque(false);
    this.setBorderPainted(false);
    this.setFocusPainted(false);

}
```

not working either

Trying with overriding paintComponent :

```
public boutondesign(String nom){
    super(nom);
    this.name = nom;  
    this.addMouseListener(this); 
    this.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.setOpaque(false);
    this.setBorderPainted(false);
    this.setFocusPainted(false);

}
public void paintComponen(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

not working either :( (I also tried g.setColor(getBackground().setColor(Color.Black))

Comment: Do you use any LookAndFeel? You can try with jbutton.setContentAreaFilled(false) method.

Comment: Hello,not working :( I edited my post

Comment: I guess you are using Mac?

Comment: yes eclipse on mac

Answer (score 1):

Following the comment of user3437460 , I looked the specifics of Mac and JButton,

there is the code working

```
public boutondesign(String nom){
    super(nom);
    this.name = nom;  
    this.addMouseListener(this); 
    this.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.setBackground(Color.black);
    this.setOpaque(true);
    this.setBorderPainted(false);
    this.setFocusPainted(false);

}
```

It seems that on Mac, Opaque attribute needs to be true, without overriding paintComponents and FocusPainted on "False"

Thanks All for your help

Answer (score 0):

This will make a black button with white text

```
this.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
this.setOpaque(true);
this.setBorderPainted(false);
```

But it is a very crude one, here it is in comparison with a basic JButton

[image]

Comment: I know this is a crude one :) but it is the first step to do a menu bar live this (french) site : https://www.qwant.com that I am trying to "copy", your Solution is still not working now :(